# How is {rlang}'s 'curly-curly' operator `{{` implemented?

Tags: r, tidyverse, metaprogramming, rlang, nse

The `{rlang}` documentation at `help("nse-force")` gives the following:

> The curly-curly operator {{ }} for function arguments is a bit special because it forces the function argument and immediately defuses it. The defused expression is substituted in place, ready to be evaluated in another context, such as the data frame.

I'm similarly confused about the 'bang-bang' operator `!!`, about which the documentation is just as obtuse regarding what's going on under-the-hood.

My question isn't about how to *use* the operator as its usage is (I think) quite straightforward. Instead I'd like to know how such an operator is actually implemented in `{rlang}` behind the scenes. According to one of the [package authors](https://twitter.com/jimhester_/status/1445419622644211713), `{{ foo }}` basically becomes `!!rlang::enquo(foo)`. However I'm still at a loss to understand how non-standard operators like this are actually *implemented*, especially considering that this one seems to 'just work', <strike>regardless of whether it's being used by `{rlang}` functions.</strike> Actually it *only* works with functions underpinned by {rlang} - thanks @Konrad Rudolph for the correction.

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang) all I can guess is that it's being done in C or C++. Can anyone give me some more information?

Comment: Minor comment: I think the title is a little ambiguous. I suggest renaming the question from "How does X work?" to "How is X implemented?".

Comment: Good suggestion - thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> However I'm still at a loss to understand how non-standard operators like this are actually *implemented*, especially considering that this one seems to 'just work', regardless of whether it's being used by {rlang} functions.

It *doesn’t* “just work” with arbitrary functions — on the contrary: functions *do* need to be aware of tidy evaluation. And as you probably guessed there’s no `{{` operator. Instead, ‘rlang’ uses NSE to capture the unevaluated argument and then checks whether the parse tree of the expression contains two nested `{` calls. It then takes the unevaluated expression and transforms it appropriately.

Comment: Thank you, this makes complete sense and you're right, I was mistaken about it working with non-rlang functions. Are you able to link to the code that does this on github?

Comment: @BluVoxe The actual recognition of the curly-curly “operator” happens here: https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/blob/3ba19df8b234ca328dfd703085d2499a6790bd29/src/internal/nse-inject.c#L45-L46; the transformation into a bang-bang-enquo happens here: https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/blob/3ba19df8b234ca328dfd703085d2499a6790bd29/src/internal/nse-inject.c#L308-L311. But I’d like to emphasise that the whole thing could be implemented in pure R, albeit less efficiently.

Comment: For anyone else looking, the actual pull request that implemented the feature is [here](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/commit/d0901598065afcf41dcb55adb6272aca666b7b26)